# How to generate a new button with a button click instantly without relaunching the application?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm trying to generate a new button item when I click on a button generator. It is able to generate but it will only show up on the screen after I relaunch the application. But I want it to be generated instantly and show up in the current view. Any suggestions? I know it's related to the `viewDidLoad` function. Anyway please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say this is your view controller method that creates buttons:

```
-(void)generateButton:(id)sender {
  UIButton *button = [UIbutton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 40)];
  [self.view addSubview:button];
  [button release];
}
```

In order to be visible you have to add the button as a subview of a current showing view.  In this case I am adding it to the main root level view for this view controller.

Comment: sorry i got it because of my button add to the wrong view and not visible,ur code are right

Answer (score 0):

When you add a subview to a view, it should be displayed immediately. Most likely, you're doing something very wrong which is resulting in the view not displaying when it should. Another thing, how are the views only showing up next launch? It sounds like you are actually persisting them somehow, which could be adding to the trouble caused by whatever you're doing. If this were IRC, I'd suggest you paste some code, because without that, there's little way to know what you're actually doing that could be causing so much trouble.